# Count specific records from an existing recordset without using the select count method

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a recordset from an sql query, from which I get the following result:

```
 ---------------
| Column_Color  |
|---------------|
| Blue          |
| Red           |
| Magenta       |
| Red           |
| Grey          |
```

As you can see, I have 2 records with the **RED** color.

I wonder if there is any possible way or method to **count** all the records having the RED color, from the column `Column_Color` ?

I am trying to avoid creating a new query with the `SELECT COUNT` method and I want to know if there is any possible method to count the RED colors, from the existing recordset. The desired result is to have the number 2 as a result.

My real recordset is bellow: I want to calculate the field named dbo.Products.F_antislip_sub

```
<%
Dim RS_proionta
Dim RS_proionta_cmd
Dim RS_proionta_numRows

Set RS_proionta_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
RS_proionta_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_sindesi_STRING
RS_proionta_cmd.CommandText=sql_q 'Here is my query...
RS_proionta_cmd.Prepared = true

Set RS_proionta = RS_proionta_cmd.Execute
RS_proionta_numRows = 0
%>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using COUNT?

Comment: @ThatGuyInIT: I am already completely LOST inside this page due to the many lines of code and due to the many SELECT statements. That’s why I am trying to avoid another one SELECT COUNT statement.
Also, the information that I need already exists in my recordsets so why not to try to get it. But now its OK after adding the filter in my existing recordset. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you set your recordset's [CursorLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee252442%28v=bts.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property to `adUseClient` you can move between records and apply filters locally.

```
Const adUseClient = 3
Dim RS_proionta
Dim RS_proionta_cmd
Dim RS_proionta_numRows

Set RS_proionta_cmd = CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
RS_proionta_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_sindesi_STRING
RS_proionta_cmd.CommandText=sql_q 'Here is my query...
RS_proionta_cmd.Prepared = true

Set RS_proionta = CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
RS_proionta.CursorLocation = adUseClient
RS_proionta.Open RS_proionta_cmd

RS_proionta.Filter = "Column_Color = 'Red'" 'filter Reds
Dim redCount 
redCount = RS_proionta.RecordCount 'redCount must equals to 2 now
Response.Write "There are " & redCount & " reds."
RS_proionta.Filter = "" 'remove filter
If Not RS_proionta.EOF Then
    RS_proionta.MoveFirst ' move cursor back to beginning
End If

'now other jobs with RS_proionta can be done again from scratch

RS_proionta.Close
```

Notice: This method should not always be considered the fastest way. If your recordset is a bulky one with lots of rows and columns with large data, an explicit `Select Count` query may be faster than this thanks to database server optimizations and server-side cursors.

Comment: @Freddakos It is required, but missing. I'm updating.

Comment: @Freddakos No need to be sorry, it was my fault. You're welcome, so "parakalo" :)